# Apache Storm InvalidTopologyException while submitting topology

Tags: apache-storm

I am getting invlaidtopologyexception while submitting my storm topology.
Here is the code:

```
TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
topologyBuilder.setSpout("konnect_smstags_spout",new Konnect_SMSTags_Spout(zkConnString,topic).getKonnectSMSTagsSpout());
topologyBuilder.setBolt("smstag_logger_bolt", new SMSTag_Logger_Bolt(),5).shuffleGrouping("konnect_smstags_spout");
topologyBuilder.setBolt("smstag_basicsummary_bolt", new SMSTag_BasicSummary_Bolt(),1).globalGrouping("smstag_logger_bolt");
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Maybe there's something wrong with your spout and logger bolt's declareOutputFields methods? Could you post those too?

Comment: I found the solution. In the smstag_logger_bolt, I was emitting something, but didn't declare fields assuming I am not using field grouping. But it seems it is compulsory to declare output fields, even if not used.